# what is the equivalent of += operator in clojure

Tags: clojure

what is the most correct way to translate this c++ code to clojure?

Code sample: `if((J%2) == 0) {det += src[0][J]*calcDet( min, ord-1)};}`

Comment: more context? is this used while iterating through `J` (equal to  length `(count (first src))`)  if so, that would heavily influence the suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the C++ code the value of `det` is being changed. Here a new value for `det` is being returned:

```
(fn [calcDet src ord min det J]
  (if (zero? (mod J 2))
    (+ det (* (nth (nth src 0) J)
              (calcDet min (dec ord))))
    det))
```

It is *most correct* to be removing mutability from your code.

`J` and `det` seem to be the only variables that are changing, so I've put them together as the last two args. You might want to `reduce` over values of `J`, where `det` is the accumulator, in which case use `partial` to get a function that leaves the last two args yet to be provided.

Alternatively you could `iterate` over a similar function, generating a lazy list of new states, where each state is `[J det]`.

There is no equivalent to `+=` in Clojure.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the expression being computed that you want to add to `det` looks like this:

```
(* (get-in src [0 J]) (calcDet min (dec ord)))
```

Your `if`, assuming that there is no else, looks like this:

```
(when (even? J)
   ... do something)
```

And an `if` with an `else` branch looks like:

```
(if (even? J)
  ... do something
  ... otherwise, do something else)
```

To add numbers, you do:

```
(+ 1 2 3)
```

However, when it comes to `+=` ...

To think clojurically means to think about evaluating expressions. Values are not changeable. Instead of **changing** `det`, what do you *really* want to do? Well, you want to calculate some value to add to whatever value you have currently bound to the name `det`. Then, you can either bind that result to a name, or feed it into another expression. No state, just evaluating expressions.

That being said, without larger context it's pointless to think of an "equivalent," because the whole approach to the problem would be different.

Looping, indexed arrays, and in-place mutation are all features of your code snippet. While these are consistent with modern hardware architecture (aka, "computer speak"), they are sometimes not consistent with the way our human brains naturally approach problems. So a level of abstraction on top of this often allows us to "zoom out" and look at the problem as a whole, where we often find a neater solution, if given tools to do so.

So, without knowing the context of this code, there is no "equivalent," at least not an idiomatic one. I specifically did not mention atoms, which are one of clojure's mechanisms to keep and mutate state, as they are certainly not applicable for this bit of code.